# Claims must have a single object value 'id_token'

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, google-signin, xwiki

I want to configure xwiki with google sign in by using OpenId connect but getting the error for id-token claim. Following pictures contains information about xwiki.properties and error.[xwiki.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4IPO.png)

[image: Token Id claim]